# How to get all traffic in the network to a specific site to be directed through a proxy?

Tags: router, proxy, routing

One of the servers in my LAN is running a certain SOCKS proxy, through which I'd like all traffic to example.com, from the entire LAN, to be automatically routed through without any configuration on the other computers.

My idea was to somehow configure the router (a TP-Link TL-WR1043N) to direct all traffic destined to example.com to the local server, which will in turn direct that traffic through the local SOCKS proxy.

Is that at all possible with the standard firmware? Below is a shot of the "Static routing list" page of the router's admin, just in case it happens to be useful for the solution to this... 
Installing DD-WRT or the likes doesn't work well on this router (results in frequent connection drops)

Any other ideas for achieving the same end result would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: As a practical matter i don't think this is possible - at least not with your router. You would either need a) the browser to decide to send traffic of some URLs to a proxy, or b) a transparent proxy that can intercept the HTTP request, and redirect them through a proxy. i don't think even Squid has such an option.

Comment: Is this for convenience or for security? Does it matter if it can trivially be evaded?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz for convenience. It doesn't matter if it can be trivially evaded.

Comment: Then just configure the router to tell people (using DHCP) to use a nameserver that resolves the domain you wish to proxy to the private IP address of the machine running the proxy.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz great idea! except that the proxy is SOCKS which means that by merely driving that traffic to the right port on the server it probably wouldn't work.

Comment: if you were configuring individual computers then foxyproxy, and configuring individual computers, a proxy configuration script might - chrome has a switch.  you might be able to get all the individual computers configured from one computer. but i see you don't want to be configuring individual computers.

Comment: here's a general idea, since it's only www.example.com you want to go to through a proxy, then you don't need a SOCKS proxy or HTTP Proxy.   A regular port remapper  This line, listens on port 28 and redirects to that ip and port.kmint21's port mapper c:\>pm z28 67.63.50.147 80 now go to http://127.0.0.1:28 and it goes to a proxy then to www.dogpile.com So using David's method but instead of pointing to a SOCKS proxy you point to a machine on your LAN running a port mapper e.g. kmint21's proxy,which goes to www.example.com  I doubt that's what you want though 'cos you want your SOCKS!

Comment: @GJ: It makes no difference what type of proxy it is. Using the proxy is what *that machine* does once it gets the traffic. No device but that machine needs to know how to use the proxy. It just needs to capture the traffic so it can stuff it through the proxy.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz well i suppose it would make a difference if a computer makes a request to a web server, GET / HTTP/1.0  . The dest ip is some website's destination ip, the router sends it to an HTTP Proxy changing the address-the destination ip, so it goes to the HTTP Proxy Now how would the http proxy know what website it is meant to go to? Maybe if it was a transparent and port remapping type proxy that got an IP addressed not to it but to some website, then it might work. But HTTP Proxies have a special type of request more like like GET http://www.blah.com/ HTTP/1.0

Comment: @barlop: If it got to that server, it must be to `example.com`. If you want to handle more than one host, use more than one IP address. `10.0.0.0/8` gives you tens of thousands of them. (And you can tell if it's port 80 or 443 the same way.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so you have to tell the HTTP Proxy to GET http://www.example.com  HTTP/1.0    Whereas if the web browser just requested www.example.com and didn't address any proxy, then the request it used is GET / HTTP/1.0 with destination IP of example.com.So if that packet is passed to a Proxy, the Proxy would have to somehow be told that it is meant for example.com , how would it be told?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  If the router wants to send the packet to a proxy, it changes the  dest IP I suppose, now what is in the packet that would tell that proxy to go to www.example.com ? or what is in the proxy to tell it to?  You could tell the Proxy to, like my example with pm.exe a port remapping proxy. But an HTTP Proxy works differently, it gets a certain type of request. And a SOCKS proxy i'm not sure but I guess it emulates an HTTP Proxy. How would it know to go to www.example.com

Comment: @barlop: It knows to go to www.example.com because whatever software talks to it tells it to go to www.example.com using whatever method the proxy needs to know how to do that. That software knows to go to www.example.com because that's the only way traffic can reach it. The DNS relays the traffic to the software that talks to the proxy. For a proxy to work, somewhere there has to be a piece of software that talks to that proxy. The issue is only how to get the traffic to that software.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2982/discussion-between-barlop-and-david-schwartz)